# Navision OData service filter not working

Tags: web-services, odata, is-empty, navision

I have a service in Navision

`https://.......?$format=json` return me the results

```
value: [
{
  No: "000001",
  Description: "MAGE Dummy",
  Shelf_No: "",
  recVendor_Predal: "",
  ETag: "32;GwAAAAJ7BjAAMAAwADAAMAAxAAAAAAA=9;7842639340;"
},
{
  No: "10",
  Description: "Test",
  Shelf_No: "",
  recVendor_Predal: "",
  ETag: "20;GwAAAAJ7AjEAMAAAAAAA9;7683646470;"
},
{
  No: "10000",
  Description: "ALU - FC R9-290X DCII Backplate",
  Shelf_No: "",
  recVendor_Predal: "",
  ETag: "28;GwAAAAJ7BTEAMAAwADAAMAAAAAAA9;7794545540;"
},
{
  No: "100001",
  Description: "TOP Plexi - Acrylic block front DS rev 1.3",
  Shelf_No: "4M-5E",
  recVendor_Predal: "123123",
  ETag: "32;GwAAAAJ7BjEAMAAwADAAMAAxAAAAAAA=9;7842639440;"
},
....
```

If I try and filter it out with

`https://.......?$format=json$filter=recVendor_Predal%20ne%20%27%27` it returns me the same results, like the filter would be ignored.

But if I use the same filter for another properties, then the filter have an affect :

`https://.......?$format=json$filter=Shelf_No%20ne%20%27%27` returns

```
{
  No: "100001",
  Description: "TOP Plexi - Acrylic block front DS rev 1.3",
  Shelf_No: "4M-5E",
  recVendor_Predal: "123123",
  ETag: "32;GwAAAAJ7BjEAMAAwADAAMAAxAAAAAAA=9;7842639440;"
},
{
  No: "100004",
  Description: "SPOJKA Hitra M Barb 10mm - Black",
  Shelf_No: "4O-7A",
  recVendor_Predal: "",
  ETag: "32;GwAAAAJ7BjEAMAAwADAAMAA0AAAAAAA=9;7683646500;"
},
....
```

What could be wrong,..

Comment: What type of the object is published in Nav as web service and what is the type of the field that fails filtering?

Comment: field is String

Comment: Is this normal field or FlowField/FlowFilter or calculated variable?

Comment: It is a normal field... The only difference is, that is from different table - connected by page

Comment: Page can have only one source table and filters can only be applied to the field of that table. I can assume that this restriction applies to pages published as web services as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the second filter works but have you tried using &$filter... istead of just $filter?
Like https://.......?$format=json&$filter=recVendor_Predal%20ne%20%27%27

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30364750)